# JQuery: how to preface a script within the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <script>
        /* set #splash-bg height */
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            var splashbgHeight = $("#meat").css("top");
            $("#splash-bg").css("height",splashbgHeight);
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var splashbgHeight = $("#meat").css("top");
                $("#splash-bg").css("height",splashbgHeight);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have this script in an HTML document in the body tag. Must I preface it with $( document ).ready() or something of the sort?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all events in jquery to execute after    DOM has loaded then use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){//your code here})
```

Comment: So then $(window).on('load',function(){ executes the script right when the page begins loading as the page is loading?

Comment: Yes that's the reason